# Java/processing about declaration of objects and sanity checks

Tags: java, processing

Sorry for such a basic question, how do I declare a class object in java such that i can access it in the methods etc of other classes? and how do i sanity check for an objects existence?

I've been using processing for an assignment, and doing it in the setup() method didn't work, so i just started declaring array[1] of class objects and using (array.size() > 0) for sanity checks. Its gotten to the point where I really need to fix this for readability of my own code. :S

Comment: very unclear. Can you provide some code that illustrates the problem?

Comment: Generally speaking, you'd just make sure that the class is `public`.

Comment: arrays don't have `size()` method, Lists do. Arrays have `length` field though. It is indeed very unclear. Try edting the question adding a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Okay so ive gone back to actually rewrite my code so now i can give an example. MyClass is contained in a class file, and this all works if i make a list of class objects and check if the list has stuff in it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it helps, but you could use Class.forName , it throws a ClassNotFoundException if the Class isn't available at runtime.

Comment: This is a serious question - in what circumstance would any code that can't find a referenced class compile but not run?

Comment: In certain cases when you are using reflection, parts of the code will be compiled and executed at runtime, the main class however will run despite it, you can actually load a .class file inside another program at runtime. The referenced class might or might not run. Most of the frameworks use reflection patterns for dynamic code plugins. There are through the instrumentation class.